# Setting ntree and mtry explicitly in Random Forest with caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

I am trying to explicitly pass the number of trees and `mtry` into the Random Forest algorithm with caret:

```
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
repGrid<-expand.grid(.mtry=c(4),.ntree=c(350))
controlRep <- trainControl(method="cv",number = 5)

rfClassifierRep <- train(label~ .,
                      data=overallDataset,
                      method="rf",
                      metric="Accuracy",
                      trControl=controlRep,
                      tuneGrid = repGrid,)
```

I get this error:

```
Error: The tuning parameter grid should have columns mtry
```

I tried doing the more sensible way first:

```
rfClassifierRep <- train(label~ .,
                      data=overallDataset,
                      method="rf",
                      metric="Accuracy",
                      trControl=controlRep,
                      ntree=350,
                      mtry=4,
                      tuneGrid = repGrid)
```

But that resulted in an error stating that I had too many hyperparameters. This is why I have tried to make a 1x1 grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ntree` cannot be part of `tuneGrid` for Random Forest, only `mtry` (see the detailed catalog of tuning parameters per model [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html)); you can only pass it through `train`. And inversely, since you tune `mtry`, the latter cannot be part of `train`.

All in all, the correct combination here is:

```
repGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry=c(4))  # no ntree

rfClassifierRep <- train(label~ .,
                      data=overallDataset,
                      method="rf",
                      metric="Accuracy",
                      trControl=controlRep,
                      ntree=350, 
                      # no mtry
                      tuneGrid = repGrid)
```